# API Data Extraction - Python

Tags: python, api

I'm trying to extract data from this API:https://www.balldontlie.io/#get-all-stats with the following code in python:

```
import requests
import json
import time

total_results = []
pages_to_read = 11000
counter = 0

for page_num in range(1, pages_to_read + 1):
    url = "https://balldontlie.io/api/v1/stats?per_page=100&page=" + str(page_num)
    print("reading", url)
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()
    total_results = total_results + data['data']
    counter = counter+ 1
    print(counter)
    if counter == 59:
        counter = 0
        print('break')
        time.sleep(60)

print("Total of", len(total_results), "results")

with open('test.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as d:
    json.dump(total_results, d, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

However, I always get this error: https://cdn1.gnarususercontent.com.br/1/292460/5c2858ca-33df-4bd8-9b44-0d50a48ab3e0.png

The API should support 60 requests per second, sometimes it even goes beyond 60, but in the end it always gets this error. Does anyone have any suggestions to help me?

PS: I would need data from all 11000 pages of 'stats'. Only the json 'data' data of the page, not counting the 'meta data' and the page number.

Comment: If you try to access some APIs very rapidly, you can get errors after a while (e.g., HTTP 502 - bad gateway). After *get()* try *response.raise_for_status()*. This will raise an exception if the HTTP status is not 200

Comment: @BrutusForcus just tried it, didn't work, i get this error: 


`raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='balldontlie.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/stats?per_page=100&page=2 (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:748)'),))`

Comment: Which just goes to prove that not all of your HTTP GET requests are succeeding and is the source of your problem

Comment: You're also likely to get HTTP 429 errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this answer:

```
import requests
import json
import time
from datetime import datetime

resultados_totais = []
paginas_totais_para_ler = 11486

def get_api_data(page_num): 
    url = "https://balldontlie.io/api/v1/stats?per_page=100&page=" + str(page_num)

    current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    print("{} - Lendo {}".format(current_time, url))
    
    start_request = datetime.now()
    response = requests.get(url)

    end_request = datetime.now()
    delta = end_request - start_request

    if delta.seconds <= 0:
        time.sleep(1)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        response.raise_for_status()
        return data['data']
    else:
        current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        print("{} - ({}) Limite de request ... aguardando 15 seg para tentar novamente".format(current_time, response.status_code))
        time.sleep(15)
        return get_api_data(page_num)

for page_num in range(1, paginas_totais_para_ler + 1):
    resultados_totais.extend(get_api_data(page_num))
    if page_num == paginas_totais_para_ler:
        print('\nSalvando Arquivo json..')
        with open('all_stats.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as d:
            json.dump(resultados_totais, d, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
        print('\nArquivo Salvo!!')

print("\nTemos um total de", len(resultados_totais), "resultados.")
```